# Where do combustibles(gas etc.) fit into the first law?

Tags: thermodynamics, combustion

The first law can be written as $dU=dW + dQ$. As I understand it $W$, work, is mechanical energy from winding up springs, things spinning, flying etc. It's kinetic and potential. As I understand it $Q$, heat, is energy in the microscopic collisions between atomic particles.

So, I can produce a $dU$, a change in internal energy, by introducing springs, billard balls, heating it up etc. But what If I place gas or TNT in my system? Is that a work contribution or a heat contribution or both? The material will combust and send particles flying, introducing kinetic energy, and it will heat the system up. What to do? Thanks!

Comment: Note that both heat and work are *energy transfers*. That is they are properties of interactions, not properties of objects or systems. Combustion releases energy from chemical storage into microscopic modes so as far as I know most texts treat the energy input as heat.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you for your comment, but isn't one characteristic of heat that it produces a temperature increase? Adding gasoline without igniting it would surely not produce a temperature increase. Thanks!

Comment: So if you are not prepared to consider the chemical potentials, then you model the injection of fuel and simple an addition of mass and particles, but you models the *burning* of the fuels as a change in the number of particles *and* plus a heat term representing the liberated energy.